# How do I build my project with Meson or Bazel when I want to use Folly as a dependency?

Tags: bazel, meson-build, bazel-rules, folly, meson-cmake-module

Folly is built using CMake, but I have a project that is built with Meson or Bazel and I want to include Folly as a dependency. How can I achieve this?

When I try to build my project using Bazel or Meson on my Mac with an M2 Pro chip running macOS version 14.3.1 (23D60), I encounter many errors. I have already installed Folly via Homebrew.

Comment: https://github.com/storypku/rules_folly